# Dynamic CRM : Need to update Connection entities via API

Tags: dynamics-crm

I have created connection via API through below code([Dynamics Crm: creating Connection entities via API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15811518/dynamics-crm-creating-connection-entities-via-api):-)

```
Entity connection = new Entity("connection");
connection["record1id"] = new EntityReference("contact", someContactId);
connection["record1objecttypecode"] = new OptionSetValue(2);
connection["record1roleid"] = new EntityReference("connectionrole",    someConnectionRoleId);
connection["record2id"] = new EntityReference("incident", someCaseId);
connection["record2objecttypecode"] = new OptionSetValue(122);
connection["record2roleid"] = new EntityReference("connectionrole", someOtherConnectionRoleId);
var newId = service.Create(connection);
```

**Question:** I need to update connection role between two records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you just need to proceed along the same road, using the Id you get from the `Create` to reference the record:

```
// Your code
Entity connection = new Entity("connection");
connection["record1id"] = new EntityReference("contact", someContactId);
connection["record1objecttypecode"] = new OptionSetValue(2);
connection["record1roleid"] = new EntityReference("connectionrole",    someConnectionRoleId);
connection["record2id"] = new EntityReference("incident", someCaseId);
connection["record2objecttypecode"] = new OptionSetValue(122);
connection["record2roleid"] = new EntityReference("connectionrole", someOtherConnectionRoleId);
var newId = service.Create(connection);

// And then ...

connection = new Entity("connection"); // start from scratch
connection["connectionid"] = newId; // needed for the CRM to know what to update
connection["record1roleid"] = new EntityReference("connectionrole",    yetAnotherConnectionRoleId);
connection["record2roleid"] = new EntityReference("connectionrole", yetAnotherAnotherConnectionRoleId);

service.Update(connection);
```